# How to set a string in FirebaseDatabase child reference

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

i am building a video content application. My aim is to get a Button id value from a different activity and use it as a child's name to load the right URL. however, i'm stuck since String link is not recognized and shows error "cannot resolve symbol 'link'.

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference mrootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mlinkRef = mrootRef.child(link);
PlayerView playerView;
SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String link = extras.getString("key");
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

variable link is defined in the scope inside the if statement and can be used only there.

```
public class MediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference mrootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mlinkRef;
PlayerView playerView;
SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String link = extras.getString("key");
        mlinkRef = mrootRef.child(link);
    }
```

Comment: can i make variable link accessible outside the scope ? Because i have tried your suggestion and it worked. However,  variable mlinkRef became inaccessible this time.

Comment: Thanks DoubleD i appreciate your help. variable link is accessible now! Didn't read your answer correctly at first.